# How to schedule a shell script using crontab

Tags: scripts

I want to schedule a shell script to run everyday excluding sunday at 7:30 pm using crontab can you please help

Answer (score 2):

Check this tool, it will help you to build the crontab line: http://www.corntab.com/pages/crontab-gui

Quick answer:

```
30 7 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6 /your/command/to/run
```